# bootstrap3 table-bordered without outside borders

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, border, borderless

I want to use a bootstrap 3 table with borders, eg using `class="table table-bordered"`, so that I'll have borders between cells, but **I don't want any borders on the outsides of the table**.

I tried the following, and it seems to work well for the sides, but I can't think of a nice way to handle the potential top and bottom borders considering that `thead` and `tfoot` are optional elements. I was hoping to make something robust that would account for these scenarios, maximizing resuse potential.

```
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders {
    border: none;
}

.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>thead>tr>td:first-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>thead>tr>th:first-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tfoot>tr>td:first-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tfoot>tr>td:first-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tbody>tr>td:first-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tbody>tr>th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>thead>tr>td:last-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>thead>tr>th:last-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tfoot>tr>td:last-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tfoot>tr>th:last-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tbody>tr>td:last-child,
.table-bordered.no-outside-borders>tbody>tr>th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Is there a nice css solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday, the css code I used for this was:

```
    .table-borderless tbody tr td, .table-borderless tbody tr th, .table-borderless thead tr th {
    border: none;
    max-height: 200px; 
    font-size: 20px;

    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table.table-borderless {


    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    max-height: 200px; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
```